# Making a Double Loop with Specified Indices $(i,j)$

Tags: procedural-programming

I want to make a double loop with `Do`. Let me first make a simple example. Consider the following simple double loop

```
Do[f[i,j]=i*j,{i,{1,2}},{j,{1,2}}]
```

does the job for $(i,j)=(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)$ respectively. Now, suppose that I just want to do the same job but for $(i,j)=(1,1),(2,2)$. Clearly, one can use if statements inside `Do` but I don't like such a solution since as the range of $(i,j)$ becomes large the process becomes time consuming. Also, if there is not any pattern for the range of loop indices $(i,j)$ then making use of if statements becomes complicated.

Now, let us express the general problem. Suppose that we have a random list for index $i$ and another random list for index $j$. I want to do a sequence of operations for each $(i,j)$ inside a `Do` loop. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you just want to loop over one variable you would write `Do[f[i,i]=i*i,{i,1,2}]`.  Personally I would just store the numbers in a list `flist=Table[i*i,{i,1,2}]`.

Comment: @ErichMueller: This is not my original problem. I may restate my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bastian already showed [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) but that function builds output (and uses memory) that I suspect you do not want.  Here is another approach using a single separate index:

```
a = {1,2};
b = {1,2};

Do[f[i,i] = a[[i]]*b[[i]], {i, 2}]
```

*Update*: looking again I think I misunderstood and instead you would want something like:

```
Do[(f[##] = #*#2) &[a[[i]], b[[i]]], {i, 2}]
```

In either case the index approach should be applicable with adjustment.

Consider also using an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) as an alternative to [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) function definitions.

```
fn = <| MapThread[{#, #2} -> #*#2 &, {a, b}] |>
```

> ```
> <|{1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 4|>
> ```

You can then use `fn` like `fn[{1, 1}]` to get your value.

Also be aware of [`Scan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html), which could be applied in this manner:

```
Scan[Apply[(f[##] = #*#2) &], {a, b}\[Transpose]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I think such an option for `Do` seems necessary! In fact, I have lots of other works to do inside my original `Do` loop and I just posted a simple example here. I have a random list for index $i$ and a random list for index $j$ and I want to do a list of operations for each $(i,j)$. Do you know any other alternatives. :)

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question. :)

Comment: I don't understand your objection to the single index approach.  It seems applicable to your updated answer.  If one were to make a "nicer" syntax for it would that be a solution in your eyes?  If you actually what the behavior of `Do` this is probably the best way.  There are related but distinct methods such as `Scan` but it is hard to recommend one thing over another without a better sense of what you are trying to accomplish.  (I added a quick example of `Scan` for reference, in case my intent was not clear.)

Comment: Ah! Sorry. you are right. Single index approach does the job nicely. :) My brain was just locked on something else! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you always have (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) etc. just use f[i,i] = i*i.

In general: Note that in Mathematica it is nicer to use functional coding style instead of a procedural one. For your case it would be most easy to use

```
MapThread[f[#1,#2] = #1*#2 &, {{1,2},{1,2}}]]
```

Comment: Then MapThread would be the easiest way: MapThread[f[#1,#2] = #1*#2 &, {list1, list2}]

Comment: (+1) I usually have random lists. :) Also, my main code consist of many other commands in the loop which depend on $(i,j)$. Your solution is nice for just evaluating a function at some points. :)

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question. :)

Comment: If you want to use MapThread this could be done by defining a dummy function: fun[i_, j_] := Module[{}, Sequence of Operations]